# Usar comando cd en QT

Tags: qt

Hola estoy intentando aprender a usar comandos en QT con cmd Puedo hacer lo siguiente:

```
QProcess consola;
consola.start("cmd.exe /C " + comando);
consola.waitForFinished();
consola.waitForReadyRead();
```

Como puedo hacer para usar cd .. por ejemplo o cd a una ubicación de mi carpeta en QT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para eso debes usar la clase `QDir` de esta manera podrás acceder a los directorios y sus contenidos.

Cuando la tengas usa las siguientes funciones para moverte entre directorios:

```
cd(const QString & dirName)
cdUp()
```

O para crear directorios:

```
mkdir(const QString & dirName) const
```

Para usar la librería no dudes en importar-la:

```
#include <QDir>
```

Aquí te dejo toda la información que puedes necesitar: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html

[qt](/questions/tagged/qt)

Comment: necesito que lo haga en cmd

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el metodo `QProcess::setWorkingDirectory` y recomiendo usar `QProcess` con setters, por ejemplo:

```
QProcess cmd;

QStringList argumentos;
argumentos << "/C" << comando;

cmd.setProgram("cmd.exe");
cmd.setArguments(argumentos);
cms.setWorkingDirectory("..") // o "../otrodirectiorio/relativo"
cmd.start(); // todos los parametros previamente "setteados"
```

Asi podras cambiar la carpeta de trabajo, saludos!